# Updating project to CocoaPods 1.0.0 resulting in many errors

Tags: ios, xcode7, cocoapods

I am working on updating some of my libraries to work with CocoaPods 1.0.0.

I have updated my Podfile to use the new DSL syntax and ran `pod update` which seemed to work as expected.

Problem 1:

I now have a bunch of errors I have never seen before in my project mainly

`Ambiguous use of internal linkage declaration XXX defined in multiple modules`

Does anyone know what this error means and how to fix it?

Problem 2:

`#import <CocoaPodName/Header.h>` style imports can no longer find the appropriate header file.

Problem 3:

`FBSnapshotTestCase` will no longer build and gives the error `Use of private header outside of module scope...`

**All of these problems began as soon as I ran `pod update` after updating to CocoaPods 1.0.0.**

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'App' do
    ...

    target 'Tests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'FBSnapshotTestCase'
    end
end
```

**Update:**

I was able to get everything to compile by removing `use_frameworks!` from the `Podfile` and using `pod 'FBSnapshotTestCase/Core`.

Ideally I would prefer to be able to use `use_frameworks!`, but it seems there may be a bug in CocoaPods 1.0.0?

Comment: For me the Podfile looks strange. Please provide the whole Podfile with a right code formatting.

Comment: Is it possible you have also updated individual Pods?

Comment: Not in this case, I have a version specified for all the pods I use.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the "Ambiguous use of internal linkage declaration XXX defined in multiple modules" errors?